Is the quotient topology space with the quotient topology homeomorphic to the topological space?
Let $G$ be a group and $X$ a set. Then an action of $G$ on $X$ is a function $F : G \times X \to X$, where we write $F(g, x) = g \cdot x$, satisfying:

For all $g_1, g_2 \in G$ and $x \in X, g_1 \cdot (g_2 \cdot x) = (g_1g_2)\cdot x$.
For all $x \in X, 1 \cdot x = x$.


Suppose $\Phi : G\times X\to X$ is an action of the group $G$ on the
set $X$. Suppose $G$ and $X$ are also topological spaces and the map
$\Phi : G\times X\to X$ is continuous $(G_x=\{g\in G:gx=x\})$. The problem is as follows: Is
the quotient topology space $G/G_x$ with the quotient topology
homeomorphic to the topological space $X$?

My attempt:
Consider the action of the additive group $\mathbb{Z}$ on the unit circle $S^1\subset\mathbb{R}^2\equiv\mathbb{C}$ given by $\Phi (n)(z)=e^{i\alpha n}z$, where $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.
I was able to show that this is a group action.
Moreover, I was hinted that  if $\alpha$ is an irrational number, then the problem posed is incorrect. Could someone explain why this implies the incorrection of the posed problem?

What does $G_x$ mean? Is it the stabilizer? If so, then $G$ would need to act transitively on $X$.

Did you compute $G/G_x$? What is the cardinality of this space? How about cardinality of $X$?

Now, try to find a counter-example where $G$ acts simply transitively.

There is always a continuous bijection $G/G_x \to G \cdot x$, but it may not be a homeomorphism... In your example, $G$ is discrete but an orbit is not.

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but if $G$ is countable, any quotient of $G$ is countable, so cannot be homeomorphic to an uncountable space like $S^1$.

@GeoffreyTrang yes

In the definition of $G_x$, $gx=g$ needs to be replaced with $gx=x$.

can someone write down the complete explanation in the answering section below so that I can understand better?

The answer is no because $G$ can be discrete at which point all its quotients will also be discrete while $X$ itself can be e.g. $S^1$, e.g. $G = \{e, g\}$ with the discrete topology and $g$ is the antipodal map. Then for a fixed $x\in S^1$ we have the stabilizer $G_x$ be the group $\{e\}$ and $G/G_x \cong G$, which is definitely not the topology of $S^1$ (e.g. $S^1$ has three disjoint open sets and $G$ doesn't.)

The stabilizer of $G_x$ is not ${e}$ when $\alpha =2\pi$.

I answered the "The problem is as follows:" part. I missed that you posed another problem in your attempt. For the circle rotation action you have, the stabilizer is the same for every point: the solution set ${ n\in\mathbb{Z} \mid e^{i\alpha n} = 1}$, which you can also write as ${ n\in\mathbb{Z} \mid \alpha n \in 2\pi \mathbb{Z}}$. There's always a solution $n=0$. There can also be a finite or infinite number of solutions. For example, when $\alpha = \pi$, the antipodal map, my analysis holds. When $\alpha = 2\pi$, the identity, $G/G_z = {e}$, again a counterexample.
